# Cant make navigation back to original tab without creating a new instance

Tags: ios

Here is my set up in storyboard.

[image]

I'm trying to use this code: (In an **IBAction** connected to the `UIBarButtonItem` in the last VC):

```
 - (IBAction)confirmClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    //EXECUTE NAVIGATION
    UITabBarController * tabControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarControl"];
    tabControl.selectedIndex = 1;

    [self presentViewController:tabControl animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

to navigate from the last ViewController in this picture to that very first `UINavigationController` in the stack. I was informed that `UINavigationController`s are not meant to be nested like this, and that only one `UINavigationController` should be necessary, but when I successfully remove(which I have done at least 5 times) the other three `UINavigationController`s from the rest of the stack, I completely lose my `UINavigationBar`s from the regular ViewControllers.

The problem with navigating the way that I currently am with my '*confirmClicked*:' method, is that I create another instance of that first `UIViewController` in the hierarchy.

Should I:

A)  Remove all the unnecessary `UINavigationController`a in the view hierarchy, then use '*popToRootViewController*:' to correctly navigate from the last VC to the first?

B)  Try to navigate another way from the last VC to the first VC, keeping the extra `UINavigationController`s in the view hierarchy?

Also, if I remove the Navigation Controllers, how will I keep my navigation bars in the UIViewControllers, since they have been disappearing in the past when removing the Navigation Controllers?

Sorry in advance for the many questions but I have been stuck for a while.

Comment: You're not using Navigation Controller properly. You only need one navigation controller. It can handle a "stack" of view controllers and navigation between them.

Comment: When you "lose" the navigation bars... what type of segue are you using?

Comment: I'm using modal segues between all of the VC's in the stack.. Oh.. should they be push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK

**First thing**

Remove all those navigation controllers. You only need one.

**Second**

The code in that IBAction is creating a brand new instance of the TabBarController and placing it over the current stack (this is how to get memory problems).

**Third**

What you probably want is either an unwind segue (possibly) or code something like this...

```
- (IBAction)confirmClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    //EXECUTE NAVIGATION
    UITabBarController * tabControl = [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: Couldn't I just `popToRootViewController:` after having only one remaining UINavigationController? Also, I believe that since I'm using modal segues, that is why the I am "losing" the navbars, I should be pushing?.. I am trying all of this right now

Comment: When I get rid of that second NavigationController and just push segue to that second VC(the first one with a container view) it keeps the navigation bar finally, but it readjusts and makes room for the tab bar??

Comment: Yes, use push segues. Also, no, you will have one navigation controller per tab. So poptorootviewcobtroller won't work to change tabs

Comment: Right, one NavController per tab.. this is all one stack coming from my second tab.. I don't want to change tabs, I just need to go all the way back to the original instance of the tab that I started at(in this case my second tab) Also I really am unsure as to why the tab bar is now being inherited through the push segue.. oh I need to set it to hides on push

Comment: No, don't hide it. That's how it works on ios. Look at any tabbed app. If you want to go back to the root vc then yeah you can poptorootviewcobtroller